# Matplotlib with PyQt5

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt

I want to read data and plot dynamic graph,
so I learn matplotlib with PyQt5.
I find example but it's for PyQt4, [there](http://hyry.dip.jp/tech/code/code.html/16)
I modify it to PyQt5 but it had some problem,
when I click start button it says error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File                                                                                                                                   
"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py",                                                                
line 1305, in _on_timer                                                                                                                                                     
    ret = func(*args, **kwargs)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py",                             
line 1049, in _step                                                                                                                                                         
    still_going = Animation._step(self, *args)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py",              
line 855, in _step                                                                                                                                                          
    self._draw_next_frame(framedata, self._blit)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py",            
line 873, in _draw_next_frame                                                                                                                                               
    self._pre_draw(framedata, blit)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py",                         
line 886, in _pre_draw                                                                                                                                                      
    self._blit_clear(self._drawn_artists, self._blit_cache)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", 
line 926, in _blit_clear                                                                                                                                                    
    a.figure.canvas.restore_region(bg_cache[a]) KeyError: matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x1067718d0
```

This is my code:

```
import sys, os, random
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.animation as animation

class MyMplCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    """Ultimately, this is a QWidget (as well as a FigureCanvasAgg, etc.)."""
    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
        # We want the axes cleared every time plot() is called
        self.axes.hold(False)

        self.compute_initial_figure()

        #
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, fig)
        self.setParent(parent)

    def compute_initial_figure(self):
        pass

class AnimationWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.canvas = MyMplCanvas(self, width=5, height=4, dpi=100)
        vbox.addWidget(self.canvas)

        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        self.start_button = QPushButton("start", self)
        self.stop_button = QPushButton("stop", self)
        self.start_button.clicked.connect(self.on_start)
        self.stop_button.clicked.connect(self.on_stop)
        hbox.addWidget(self.start_button)
        hbox.addWidget(self.stop_button)
        vbox.addLayout(hbox)
        self.setLayout(vbox)

        self.x = np.linspace(0, 5*np.pi, 400)
        self.p = 0.0
        self.y = np.sin(self.x + self.p)
        self.line, = self.canvas.axes.plot(self.x, self.y, animated=True, lw=2)




    def update_line(self, i):
        self.p += 0.1
        y = np.sin(self.x + self.p)
        self.line.set_ydata(y)
        return [self.line]

    def on_start(self):
        self.ani = animation.FuncAnimation(self.canvas.figure, self.update_line,
                                 blit=True, interval=25)

    def on_stop(self):
        self.ani._stop()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    qApp = QApplication(sys.argv)
    aw = AnimationWidget()
    aw.show()
    sys.exit(qApp.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, this worked.
You have to install the numpy -11.1 + mkl (http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) first, 
And then install the matplotlib(http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#matplotlib) module then it works fine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!!
but I have installed it already!!